# destroy WordPress PHP session based on PHPSESSID value

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cas, sessionid

I have a really limited WordPress knowledge but need to perform a following task - I have to destroy WordPress PHP session based on PHPSESSID value.

I need to handle direct call from another server(CAS server Single Logout (SLO) request) that will POST to my some WP url PHPSESSID value. Based on this PHPSESSID value I need to destroy some user session. Browser is not involved here

Please show me an example how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Wordpress does not use PHP sessions. Other than authentication cookies, there no other persistent data it needs.

In order to destroy an artbitrary session by its ID you can:

```
$your_arbitrary_session_id = 'blah-123456789'

session_id($your_arbitrary_session_id); 
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Well, it might just be about kicking out the user by PHPSESSID instead of username, then session_destroy() wouldn´t work since it´s not started with session_start().

Comment: Then it's just a matter of calling [`wp_logout()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout)

Comment: I need to handle direct call from another server that will POST to my some WP url PHPSESSID value. Based on this PHPSESSID value I need to destroy some user session. Browser is not involved here..

Comment: @alexanoid I've clarified the answer.

Comment: @chromice thanks, but it still doesn't work for some reason.. After this code I'm refreshing the page in browser and I'm still able to access secure resource..

Comment: But when I try to access http://example.com/wp-login.php it correctly shows that my session was destroyed. But how to destroy session when I try to access for example http://example.com/wp-admin/profile.php ?

Comment: I think some physical session cookie representation at WP server side must be also deleted(for example from disk).. but I don't know how..